# Using Parse.com REST API with query in node.js - how to use data-encode from CURL

Tags: node.js, curl, parse-platform

I am trying to replicate the example of the parse.com rest API below:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"John"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

So, based on an example found on Stackoverflow, I implemented the function:

```
var https = require("https");
exports.getJSON = function(options, onResult){

    var prot = options.port == 443 ? https : http;
    var req = prot.request(options, function(res){
        var output = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var obj = JSON.parse(output);
            onResult(res.statusCode, obj);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
    });

    req.end();
};
```

which I call like that :

```
var options = {
host: 'api.parse.com',
port: 443,
path: '/1/classes/GameScore',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'APP_ID',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'APP_KEY'
}
};

rest.getJSON(options,
    function(statusCode, result)
    {
        // I could work with the result html/json here.  I could also just return it
        //console.log("onResult: (" + statusCode + ")" + JSON.stringify(result));
        res.statusCode = statusCode;
        res.send(result);
    });
```

My question is, how do I send the "--data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' bit? I tried appending it to the path by setting the path in the options like that: '/1/classes/GameScore?playerName=John, but that didn't work, I received all the GameScore, not the ones from John

Comment: Why don't you just use the official Parse JavaScript SDK?  Also, you can look at its source code to see how to use the rest api. https://npmjs.org/package/parse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I tried appending it to the path by setting the path in the options like that: `/1/classes/GameScore?playerName=John`

It seems to be expecting `where` as the key/name with the value the entire JSON value:

```
/1/classes/GameScore?where=%7B%22playerName%22%3A%22John%22%7D
```

You can get this with [`querystring.stringify()`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq):

```
var qs = require('querystring');

var query = qs.stringify({
    where: '{"playerName":"John"}'
});

var options = {
    // ...
    path: '/1/classes/GameScore?' + query,
    // ...
};

// ...
```

Optionally with `JSON.stringify()` to format the value from object:

```
var query = qs.stringify({
    where: JSON.stringify({
        playerName: 'John'
    })
});
```

Comment: It is helpful answer. But I have one question, how about PUT(update)?

Comment: @smartworld-konoha You can use [`req.write(JSON.stringify({ ... }));`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding_callback) to provide the object in the request's body, along with an appropriate `Content-Type` request header, going by the [current Parse Server docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#updating-objects). – Although it uses URL-encoding rather than JSON, an example is available in the docs for [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).